# How to extract specific type of links from website using php?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract specific type of links from the webpage using php

links are like following..

http://www.example.com/pages/12345667/some-texts-available-here

I want to extract all links like in the above format.

maindomain.com/pages/somenumbers/sometexts

So far I can extract all the links from the webpage, but the above filter is not happening. How can i acheive this ?

Any suggestions ?

<?php 

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
//Create a new DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
foreach ($links as $link){
    //Extract and show the "href" attribute.
         echo $link->nodeValue;
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
}

?>

Comment: Although regex is not a good friend of HTML, I think it could work if the links are in a "area" of the page. You could then cut out that part with strpos() and then use strip_tags() to remove that tags that could cause issues with the regex. Do you have any sample data?

Comment: wait.. you only need the regex??

Comment: something like **[this](https://regex101.com/r/zG7pS3/1)**

Comment: `(?:http.*)maindomain\.com\/pages\/\d+\/.*`

Comment: thank for the reply. How can i use the above regex in my the code which i provided ?

Comment: @user3391693 which of the echo in the loop prints the links?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOMXPath and register a function with [`DOMXPath::registerPhpFunctions`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php) to use it after in an XPATH query:

```
function checkURL($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    unset($parts['scheme']);

    if ( count($parts) == 2    &&
         isset($parts['host']) &&
         isset($parts['path']) &&
         preg_match('~^/pages/[0-9]+/[^/]+$~', $parts['path']) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($filename);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xp->registerPhpFunctions('checkURL');

$links = $xp->query("//a[php:functionString('checkURL', @href)]");

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

In this way you extract only the links you want.

Comment: Damn it, I was too late - was fiddling with my answer :) I like your solution (+1), but why not use `starts-with()` in this scenario?

Comment: @Jan: `starts-with` can't work with and without the scheme part of the URL at the same time. And I think the goal isn't specially to test what is the host but more how looks the path. Note that with a function you can easily add other checks if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight guess, but if I got it wrong you can still see the way to do it.

```
foreach ($links as $link){
  //Extract and show the "href" attribute.
  If(preg_match("/(?:http.*)maindomain\.com\/pages\/\d+\/.*/",$link->getAttribute('href')){
       echo $link->nodeValue;
       echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already use a parser, so you might step forward and use an xpath query on the DOM. XPath queries offer functions like [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) as well, so this might work:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query("//a[starts-with(@href, 'maindomain.com')]");
```

Loop over them afterwards:

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
    // do sth. with it here
    // after all, it is a DOMElement
}
```